# Contenteditable prevent caret placement after a certain element

Tags: javascript, html, css, range, contenteditable

I have a certain contenteditable div, inside this div I have some  tags that are immediately followed by  tags so it will be like this

```
<span class="formatting-holder"></span>
|<b></b>|
<span class="formatting-holder-close"></span>
```

The | character denote the places where I need to prevent the caret from being positioned, the caret should only be placed inside the `<b></b>` but not between the `<span>` and the `<b>`.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: And it's not practical to have `<b contenteditable>` instead of its grandparent? or to add `font-weight: bold` to the style of the parent `<span>` so yo don't even need `<b>`?

Comment: unfortunately no, as I have some text bold and some text not bold (and may be other formats), and I need to have some wrapping spans around the bold, but in this span, there cannot exist any non bold text.

Comment: What if you rather added those "|" using CSS pseudo elements `:before` and `:after`? They wouldn't be editable and would display regardless.

Answer (score 0):

### Use CSS

One of the best ways to accomplish what you're after is by using CSS which displays your "|" characters and also prevents caret from being positioned on them

```
<span class="formatting-holder"></span>
<b></b>
<span class="formatting-holder-close"></span>
```

and in your CSS define this

```
.formatting-holder:before,
.formatting-holder:after {
    content: "|";
}
```

Comment: Oh apparently you did not fully understand what I meant, I wanted to "prevent" the caret from being, those "|" characters was just explaining